# Export transparent PNG does not work in v11

Tags: plotting, export

Below is the simple command I used:

```
Export["TransparentCircle.png", Graphics[Circle[]], Background -> None]
```

The png is not transparent in Mathematica v11, but cool in v9. I am using Windows 7 64 bit, Mathematica v11.0.0.0.

I have tried raster the graph (`Rasterize[Graphics[Circle[]], "Image", Background -> None]`) first, but still no luck. Can someone please help?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with .emf too.

Comment: Seems to work fine on 11.0.1.

Comment: I can confirm that it works on 11.0.1 and also on 10.4.1.0 on Linux.

Comment: hmm... I am downloading v11.0.1 to verify.

Comment: Still no luck... @Stitch, are you also using Windows 7?

Comment: Same configuration. How do you verify it is not transparent?

Comment: I tested the transparency by dragging the png into a PowerPoint document with color background, like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdimY.png

Comment: With versions 10.4.1, 11.0.1, 11.1.0 on Windows 7 x64 it works correctly.